# is it possible to create a graph by shell script

Tags: shell, unix, solaris-10

i want to create a graph file using shell script. For example, i want to make graph of sar output of my system.

```
sar 1 10


05:36:32 AM       CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle
05:36:33 AM       all      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00    100.00
05:36:34 AM       all      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00    100.00
05:36:35 AM       all      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00    100.00
05:36:36 AM       all      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00    100.00
05:36:37 AM       all      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00    100.00
05:36:38 AM       all      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00    100.00
05:36:39 AM       all      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00    100.00
05:36:40 AM       all      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00    100.00
05:36:41 AM       all      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00    100.00
05:36:42 AM       all      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00    100.00
Average:          all      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00    100.00
```

Comment: OK. Try something. If it doesn't work, post your code and someone will try to help.

Answer (score -1):

As a visualizer you can use [Gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/).